# How does Git proxy server work?

Tags: node.js, git, proxy

I was following Oracle Jet install setup in here till they told to setup proxy server in Git and Nodejs

> https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet201/jet/developer/GUID-ABE2373F-287F-4C3A-BEBD-02F179F399FD.htm#JETDG-GUID-C8D97F89-552F-437B-8DC1-6A92CCC196DB

I am new to the concept of proxy server in Git. I do not use any other server over the Internet then where does that proxy server come from and how does it work?

Comment: Did the docs specifically tell you to use a proxy server?  From what I saw at a glance it appeared to be just an example.  I have never had the need to use Git with a proxy server.  Where do you live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad for not reading carefully. As Tim Biegeleisen said, it was just an example, not mandatory installing step thus proxy server does not have any special meaning.